# Discord.py Application Bot [requesting-help]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/zLE7fRyT'

app_questions = requests.get(url)
questions = app_questions.text

q_list = []
q_list = questions.split("\n")

a_list = []


application_channel = config.APPLICATION_LOGS_CHANNEL

@bot.command(aliases=['application'])
async def apply(ctx):
    a_list = []
    submit_channel = bot.get_channel(application_channel)
    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()

    def check(m):
        return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel

    for question in q_list:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        await channel.send(question)
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        a_list.append(msg.content)

    submit_wait = True
    print("msg",msg)
    while msg is not None:
        await channel.send('End of questions - "submit" to finish')
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
            submit_wait = False
            answers = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(a_list, 1))
            submit_msg = f'Application from {msg.author} \nThe answers are:\n{answers}'
            print("answers", answers)
            if answers is not None:
                await submit_channel.send(submit_msg)
```

I am having issues where the questions are sometimes sending without waiting for an answer. I am currently getting this error: `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` I have tried `while submit_wait` instead of `while msg is not None:` The questions look like this:

Comment: Your bot.get_channel is returning None, Try checking if the channel id exists and is an integer. If it still doesnt work, try guild.get_channel

Comment: Yes I fixed that issue, but I am still having the problem where the messages keep double / triple sending before waiting for an answer. I sent the full code to a few friends and they said it was working perfectly for them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a bunch of other issues.

1. Why are you initializing `q_list` as `[]` before immediately assigning it to the questions right after? This is completely unnecessary.
2. `a_list` doesn't  need to be initialized outside the command. This is completely pointless. If you want to modify the variable in the global scope, use `global a_list` instead of `a_list = []` inside the command.
3. Your `check` does not make sure that the correct person is answering.
4. Your `check` does not need to make sure the message `content` is `None`, as this is impossible; a message's `content` will only ever be `str` (not `NoneType`), and it won't be empty, either, as you cannot send an empty message in Discord.
5. Your `print` statement won't print the message's contents; casting it to `str` won't get its `content`. Instead,  use `print("msg",msg.content)`.
6. `Member.create_dm()` is not necessary; you can send a message directly to a `Member`. So, setting `channel` to `ctx.author` will still allow you to `send` to them. This is because [`Member` implements `Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#messageable).
7. Your `print` statement that prints `msg` seems pointless; it will simply print the user's answer to the last question asked.
8. Be consistent with your quotes. Pick one style (`'` or `"`) and stick with it. The only time you should switch quotes is to avoid escaping quotes inside strings.
9. Your `print` statement that prints the `answers` should probably be either `print("answers",answers,sep="\n")` or `print(f"answers\n{answers}")` to avoid printing the first answer on the same line as "answers".
10. `answers` will never be `None`. How could `str.join` return `None`?